# How to install gnome-terminal in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, gnome-terminal

I need to run gnome-terminal in Cygwin in Windows environment. Gnome-terminal doesn't seem come with default Cygwin installation. I couldn't find documentation on how to install it. Does any one have idea?

Comment: You will need to install a bunch of dependencies. Do you have the base install of Gnome installed?

Comment: I installed the default version of everything in Cygwin and the full version of Gnome.

Comment: Why do you need gnome-terminal in particular? Have you tried the terminals that come with Cygwin: mintty, xterm, rxvt(-unicode)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to go about this is probably to use the [Cygwin Ports project's repository](http://sourceware.org/cygwinports/). The installation instructions include a cryptic command line, but it's not too bad.

Dennis is right through; expect to install a *lot* of dependencies. If you want something with roughly the same functionality as Gnome Terminal but doesn't depend on so many things, you might look at [Sakura](https://launchpad.net/sakura).

If you run into trouble with that, an alternative might be to try [CoLinux](http://www.colinux.org/), which runs a Linux distribution seamlessly with Windows in a fast virtual machine.

Comment: Sakura looks perfect, but I can't find any information on how to install it on a Windows machine.

Comment: @Adam, You'll need to compile it. Make sure you have g++, cmake, pkg-config, x11, and dev versions of libgtk, libvte, glib2.20, and libpcre (among other things). This is sort of a pain. Have you tried mintty?

Comment: As of November 2011, `gnome-terminal` is part of the Cygwin Ports repository; i.e., no compilation necessary. You will need the `dbus` and `dconf` packages, which are not dependencies of `gnome-terminal` but required for proper function.